# Why imageButton in a ListView does not toggle untill scrolled?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-imagebutton

I have a simple listView via a custom adapter. Each row in the list view is composed of a ImageButton and TextView.

The idea is to change the ImageButton when user taps on it and it does not work. However, ImageButton changes for the views that are scrolled and recycled. I mean, when user scrolls down the list and comes back to the top and tap on the ImageButton it works as expected for those rows that were scrolled and back again.

Can you guys help me out what i'm missing? I'm extremely new to Android and have been stuck around this for about a week now trying to fix this.

Here's the APK for the sample test app: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzlahtqkgj010m8/app-ListViewExample.apk?dl=0
Here are the relevant parts of my code:

avtivity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and to render the single row in the ListView the following xml is utilized:

single_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/b"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        style="@style/ListView.first"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

coming to the Java code,

MainActivity.java is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] titles;
    ListView list;
    private listViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res = getResources();

        titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new listViewAdapter(this, titles);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and the custom adapter listViewAdapter.java look like this

```
class sListItem {
    public ImageButton button;
    public TextView text;
    public boolean active;
}

public class listViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final String[] titles;
    Context context;

    private int size = 15;
    public sListItem mp[] = new sListItem[size];


    public listViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titles) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_row, R.id.imageButton, titles);
        this.context = context;
        this.titles = titles;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        if(mp[position] == null)
            mp[position] = new sListItem();

        mp[position].button = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        mp[position].button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp[position].active = !mp[position].active;

                setIcon(position, mp[position].active);
            }
        });

        mp[position].text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mp[position].text.setText(titles[position]);
        setIcon(position, mp[position].active);

        return row;
    }


    private void setIcon(int position, boolean active) {
        Drawable drawable;

        if(active){
            drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a);
        } else {
            drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b);
        }
        mp[position].button.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

[image: the list view in example]

**EDIT:** Added link to sample test app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell adapter to update by calling `notifydatasetchanged` in the click listener

```
 mp[position].button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp[position].active = !mp[position].active;
                setIcon(position, mp[position].active);
                notifydatasetchanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I cannot resolve the method: notifydatasetchanged() within the class. (just FYI, the custom adapter is in a separate class file)

Comment: You saved my ass! I googled up a bit and it is notifyDataSetChanged(); 
(P.S: will reward you bounty) Yay.. I will now go drink up